# R datatable rowCallback with DT

Tags: javascript, r, datatable, shiny, dt

I am trying to perform two distinct formatting operations on a datatable object using the DT and magrittr packages. One uses the helper function formatRound() and the other is passed in as JavaScript to a rowCallback option in the datatable function.

When I run either of the formatting operations individually the datatable renders with the expected formatting. However, when I run both together the datatable renders blank but I do not get an error.

This code shows the behavior I am describing.

```
library(magrittr)
library(DT)

df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10))

datatable(
  data = df
) %>%
  formatRound(c("X1", "X2"), 1)

#table renders as expected

datatable(
  data = df,
  options = list(
    rowCallback = JS("
     function( row, data, index ) {
       if ( index > 2 ) {
        $(row).css('background-color', '#EDEDED');
       }
       else if ( index > 0 ) {
        $(row).css('background-color', '#DEDEDE');
       }
       else {
        $(row).css('background-color', '#D3D3D3');
       }
     }"
    )
  )
)

#table renders as expected

datatable(
  data = df,
  options = list(
    rowCallback = JS("
     function( row, data, index ) {
      if ( index > 2 ) {
        $(row).css('background-color', '#EDEDED');
      }
      else if ( index > 0 ) {
        $(row).css('background-color', '#DEDEDE');
      }
      else {
        $(row).css('background-color', '#D3D3D3');
      }
     }"
    )
  )
) %>%
  formatRound(c("X1", "X2"), 1)

#table renders as blank but with no error returned
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a look at the JS function of  your third attempt in the browser's JS console(click on "Inspect Element option in browser"), it shows up an error saying that 'var' is unidentified because it is outside the scope of the JS function:

```
(
var d = parseFloat(data[1]); $(this.api().cell(row, 1).node()).html(isNaN(d) ? '' : d.toFixed(1));
var d = parseFloat(data[2]); $(this.api().cell(row, 2).node()).html(isNaN(d) ? '' : d.toFixed(1));
     function( row, data, index ) {
      if ( index > 2 ) {
        $(row).css('background-color', '#EDEDED');
      }
      else if ( index > 0 ) {
        $(row).css('background-color', '#DEDEDE');
      }
      else {
        $(row).css('background-color', '#D3D3D3');
      }
     })
```

If you put those two lines inside the JS function, it works perfectly.

You can find the updated code below.

```
datatable(
    data = df,
    options = list(
        rowCallback = JS("
     function( row, data, index ) {
        var d = parseFloat(data[1]); 
        $(this.api().cell(row, 1).node()).html(isNaN(d) ? '' : d.toFixed(1));
        var d = parseFloat(data[2]); 
        $(this.api().cell(row, 2).node()).html(isNaN(d) ? '' : d.toFixed(1));
       if ( index > 2 ) {
        $(row).css('background-color', '#EDEDED');
       }
       else if ( index > 0 ) {
        $(row).css('background-color', '#DEDEDE');
       }
       else {
        $(row).css('background-color', '#D3D3D3');
       }
     }"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: If the answer helps you, please accept it, that way it helps other people in the future !

Comment: Hi, instead of index > 2, if I want to write index = (last row index) in the if condition, what would be the way to write that in case of table of varying length?